How to exactly sample two Cox-Ingersoll-Ross processes that share the same Brownian motion
Lets say that I have two CIR processes
\begin{align}
dX_t &= b_x(a_x - X_t)dt + s_x \sqrt{X_t}dB_t \newline
dY_t &= b_y(a_y - Y_t)dt + s_y \sqrt{Y_t}dB_t
\end{align}
And I want to sample from these processes exactly, i.e. on the interval $[0, t]$ I want to sample from the noncentral chi-square density of both $X_t$ and $Y_t$. But I have the problem that the Brownian motion is shared. If I use Euler-Maruyama or Milsten, then I would just sample the Brownian increment and reuse it in both equations. But the goal is to sample exactly.
Has this been explored in the literature? I fail to find a reference :) Would sharing the same pseudorandom numbers be valid?

I would try your suggestion and draw a single uniform $u\sim U(0,1)$ from which I’d then calculate both noncentral chi square variates via standard inverse transform sampling. Afterwards - just to make sure - check that the Euler scheme will converge towards the same results ;)

@Kermittfrog Thanks a lot for your suggestion! The formulas look scary, do you think this would be possible to calculate exactly? Or are there still some approximations that will be involved? Otherwise, under some conditions, noncentral chi-square can be sampled as (Z + sqrt(lambda))^2 + chi^2_{nu - 1} where Z is N(0, 1) and the lambda, nu are values that depend on CIR. I can imagine using the same Z for both processes, but the degrees of freedom will be different among the processes, and therefor one may need to generate a different number of PRN.

Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function, I think you could implement the CDF inversion, although it maybe a bit cumbersome.
